# Is there any way, that program would scan picture on the screen anyhow and from it make decisions?

Tags: programming-languages, pixel, scanning

Can I scan pixels at all? What languages do let this? Please explain and give code example.

Comment: Too general. "It depends", "it depends", and "no".

Comment: I don't know enough about this to provide an answer, but I do know that this is how the fishing bots in Final Fantasy XI Online worked. They would read pixels from the screen of a certain colour, count them and make a decision to "reel in the fish" or wait for another nibble, etc. So it's definitely possible, but I don't know exactly how it was implemented. You're in the realm of graphics programming.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with this by the way? If you provide an example of what you are trying to achieve and your prior knowledge, then it would be easier for people to provide a better answer.

Comment: For leif: I just wanted to know is it possible, I am thinking of creating clickbot (for my-self-usage) for one game. :D And now when I know that this is possible, i'll find the way to do it. Thx for an answer anyway.

Answer (score 1):

In C# you can get an screenshot like this:

```
Bitmap image
try
{
   image = new Bitmap(1024, 768);
   Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(image);
   g.CopyFromScreen(new Point(0, 0), new Point(0, 0), new System.Drawing.Size(1024, 768));
}
catch { }
```

Now, you can read pixels like this:

```
Color color = image.GetPixel(0, 0);
```